# Vba - why xlHistogram does not work?

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I need to build a simple histogram chart in Microsoft Excel 2016, but there is something wrong here:

```vb
Sheet.addchart2(range, xlHistogram,,,,)
```

It works with all the others types but this one. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: The syntax for AddChart2 is `AddChart2([Style], [XlChartType], [Left], [Top], [Width], [Height], [NewLayout])`. Range isn't supposed to be in there. You use `SetSourceData` or other commands to tell the chart what data to use.

Answer (score 4):

The new Excel charts introduced in 2016 require a different technique. Microsoft confirms that this is a bug. A workaround is to select a range and then add the chart. Along the lines of:

```
.Range("A1:B7").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlHistogram).Select
```

For more details look at [this page](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=0GDcCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT525&lpg=PT525&dq=xlHistogram&source=bl&ots=8LgMBHUWm8&sig=YuI4nsR8Tcr3cSCl2wkIfg-LdUA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzo9rjorXNAhWJKJQKHXgYCEsQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=xlHistogram&f=false) in the book "Excel 2016 VBA and Macros"